# Why did the Greek debt crisis raise gold prices?

Tags: gold

Greece is a small country. Shouldn't the bad economic practices of just one small country not drive prices up so high?

Comment: You'd have to ask this on the economics site.

Comment: *Did* the Greek debt crisis raise gold prices? [Correlation does not imply causation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greece is in the EU, so the whole EU system backed Greece and gave them basically free money. That caused concerns, after all, many countries in the EU are already doing badly and now they had to help out another country. All of this strengthened the EU opposition and it became a possibility that the EU would fall apart. In theory